# which way of creating and appending an element is faster in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to append some div elements to my page. There are two ways:
Way 1 (appending a complete string):

```
$('#page123').append("<div id='foo' class='checkbox' data-quesid='foofaa'><label class='control-label'>Question<span class='quesNo'>"+ quesNo +"</span>: <span class='q'>" + title +"</span></label></div>")
```

Way 2(cloning html element, populating it and then appending):

```
var question = $('div.sampleQuestionLayOut').first().clone(true);
question.removeClass('sampleQuestionLayOut');
question.removeAttr('style');

question.attr('id', 'foo');
question.attr('data-quesid', 'foofaa');
......so on

$('#page123').append(question);
```

Obviously, in way 2, I am writing a sample html element to select it and populate it and append. In my html file:

```
<div id='' class='checkbox sampleQuestionLayOut' data-quesid='' style='display:none'>
  <label class='control-label'>
    Question
    <span class='quesNo'></span>: 
    <span class='q'></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Now I may be appending such question 20 times on my page. Which of the above way is more efficient in terms of performance and also which is a better way to code?

Comment: How do I discover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method ought to be little bit faster, because it deals less with the DOM.

Here is a small test using `performance.now()` to measure execution time:

```
$(function() {

  var s1 = performance.now();
  $('#page123').append("<div id='foo' class='checkbox' data-quesid='foofaa'><label class='control-label'>Question<span class='quesNo'>2</span>: <span class='q'>2</span></label></div>")
  var e1 = performance.now();
  console.log('StringAppend: ' + (e1 - s1) + ' ms');

  var s2 = performance.now();
  var question = $('div.sampleQuestionLayOut').first().clone(true);
  question.removeClass('sampleQuestionLayOut');
  question.removeAttr('style');
  question.attr('id', 'foo');
  question.attr('data-quesid', 'foofaa');
  question.html("<label class='control-label'>Question<span class='quesNo'>1</span>: <span class='q'>1</span></label>")
  $('#page123').append(question);
  var e2 = performance.now();
  console.log('CloneAndAppend: ' + (e2 - s2) + ' ms');

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s1odw6pg/1/

I might add that generally speaking you should try to minimize the number of invocations of the `append()` method and thus the DOM-manipulations operations. If your elements need to appear one after another you can build a big HTML-string and append it all together. An interesting resource to see different approaches to this is the following: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the best way to achieve the best performance with jQuery is to create the whole markup (using a string) and call .append(string) only once (option #1).

Doing that, you'll just be working with the DOM once (where Javascript is slower) instead of multiple/several times (option #2).

Answer (score -1):

As it is, the first method should be marginally faster as it doesn't seek the template element first. As for best practice, I'm unsure. I'd prefer the second , but it can get pretty subjective.

[WRONG] The second approach should be faster, as it wouldn't need to parse the markup as well.

Edit- i should really pay more attention. I quickly skimmed through it and thought you were creating it from scratch in method 2. (which would have been the fastest way)

Comment: How are you determining the speed?

Comment: Just general experience with this type of things. In any case, if you want to be exact about it, you can use chrome's profiler to find out the specific difference. Should be along the lines of what I said. In any case, this smells of premature optimization :D